# Web API working for embedded URI not for Query String

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, rest, asp.net-core

I have two API end points as in the below.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class StudentController : ControllerBase
{
   IStudentRepository studentRepository;
   public StudentController(IStudentRepository studentRepository)
    { 
      this.studentRepository = studentRepository;
    }
    
   [HttpGet]
   public ActionResult<IEnumerable<Student>> GetStudents()
   {
      return Ok(studentRepository.GetStudents());
   }
    
   [HttpGet]
   [Route("{Id}")]
   public ActionResult<Student> GetStudent([FromRoute,FromQuery]int Id)
   {
      if (Id <= 0)
       return BadRequest();
    
         return Ok(studentRepository.GetStudent(Id));
    }
}
```

The second end point GetStudent() will only be invoked when we search using the URI /api/Student/{Id} but will not work for /api/Student?Id={Id}.

Can we make a same end point work for both embedded URI and query string URI?

This was possible in .Net Framework Web API but not possible in .Net Core Web API why is it so?

Comment: @YongShun I tried but it threw an exception with a message "mutiple matching end points" as it will point to GetStudents() and also to GetStudent()

Comment: I see, apologzie for that, didn't notice that the `GetStudents` method.

Comment: I think the only way you can get the `id` from the query string via `GetStudents` method, but this will require modifying the implementation and the return type. The reason why `GetStudent` cannot get the `id` from query string as you have defined the route for this action "api/Student/{Id}", so when you call the API with "api/Student?id={Id}" it will not hit this action.

Comment: If I remove the Route("{Id}") on top of the GetStudent() then it should work for both api/Student/{Id} & api/Student?Id={Id} like it used to work in the .Net Framework but in .Net Core this will not even work for either of them.
Writing web api in .Net framework was a blessed thing :(

Comment: You can not get value both from route and query string at the same endpoint, If you send request like `api/Student?id={Id}`, It will hit `GetStudents()` endpoint.

Comment: @XinranShen yes it will hit GetStudents() in .Net Core Framework for api/Student?Id={Id} but in .Net Framework for both api/Student?Id={Id} & for api/Student/{Id}  the GetStudent() would get invoked.Why the same is not possible in the .Net Core Framework is the question. :)

Comment: It is by design, Asp.net core web Api is restful style, If you don't wanna this default style, you can change the default route attribute(`api/[controller]`)

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET Core Web API, you can use route parameters and query parameters together in the same action method, allowing you to make the same endpoint work for both embedded URI and query string URI. To achieve this, you can modify your GetStudent method as follows:

```
[HttpGet("{Id}")]
public ActionResult<Student> GetStudent([FromRoute]int Id, [FromQuery]int queryId)
{
    int searchId = Id > 0 ? Id : queryId;
    if (searchId <= 0)
        return BadRequest();

    return Ok(studentRepository.GetStudent(searchId));
}
```